# Get angle between one point and another (trigonometric functions)

Tags: java, trigonometry

I have 2 points. Base point and other point. I need to get angle in which base should move to have other point opposite to it. But possibilities are from 0 to 360 degrees not only 90.
[image]

I now it should be done with trigometry but I dont know well how. Could someone explain me what algorithms should I use? Or paste solution? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by being opposite? A point can have a single point opposite in infinite directions..?P

Comment: This is off-topic, as it's essentially a maths problem.  I suggest getting a good textbook that covers trigonometry...

Comment: Opposite to line i drawed. This line is always in north direction (o degree)

Answer (score 3):

Draw a right triangle using those points and see the angle. You would be able to find the angle because of know side of tringles, if you know coordinates of points.

Overall It should be something like:

```
double alpha = Math.atan((yb - yp) / (xb - xp));
```

where

> xb, yb are coordinates for base point
>
> xp, yp are coordinates for red point

`alpha` would in radians, not degrees.

and note that `atan` returns values from `-pi/2` to `pi/2`

Comment: How should I convert the result to degrees then? Use toDegrees() only?

Comment: @MichałTabor, yes, you can use `Math.doDegrees(alpha)`

Comment: I done as you tell and it doesnt return right values. I tried to add 90 to it and in such case I get right values when red dot is in II and IV quarter, but wrong when it is in I and III... (I is up-left most quarter).

Comment: @MichałTabor, update your question with code and examples of wrong cases. 3rd and 4th quarters you have to adjust, note the last line in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a trigometry issue, but it sounds like you basically want the angle between the red and black dots, and then to just add 180 to that angle.

However:
Math.atan2(y, x)

Can help you here, as you can give it the difference in the x co-ordinate and the difference in the y co-ordinate in order to get an angle (in radians).

You really should look up trig though, as you can learn the basic stuff in 10 minutes or so.
"SOH CAH TOA" will be useful your whole life.

Comment: oh, and remember you probably want to loop the values, so when you add 180, you dont get values over 360.
    `if (angle>360){
    angle=angle-360;
    }`
or, angle=angle%360; (if you expect angles over 720)

Answer (score -1):

The angle can be obtained by doing: angle = Math.acos(unit-vector(a).unit-vector(b)) where a and b are the vector between the base-point and initial-direction, and base-point and other point respectively  ('.' stands for dot-product) 
If you want the angle in degrees, do this: angle = (angle*180/Math.PI).

***If you do not understand vectors, and know Java, read this:***

You will need the following information:

1. Co-ordinates of Base-Point.(represented as a point object basePoint, having x and y)
2. Co-ordinates of Other-Point.(otherPoint)
3. Co-ordinates of where Base-Point was pointing to initially.(initialPoint)

(Vectors have 2 components, x and y. Declare a class for vector with double x and y, or use Point)

```
newVector(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    // returns a new vector from point a 
    //to point b given two absolute co-ordinates a and b
    vector new1 = new vector(0, 0);
    new1.x = p2.x - p1.x;
    new1.y = p2.y - p1.y;
    return new1;

}
```

**In the diagram, if you want vector(a), do newVector(basePoint, initialDirection);**

**Similarly, vector(b) = newVector(basePoint, otherPoint)**

```
unitVector(vector a)
{
    vector new1 = new vector(0,0);
    new.x = a.x/(Math.sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y));
    new.x = a.y/(Math.sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y));
    return new1;
}
```

**In the diagram, if you want unit-vector(a), do unitVector(vector(a))**

```
dotProduct(vector a, vector b)
{
    double val;
    val = a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y;
    return val;
}
```

**In the diagram, if you want unit-vector(a).unit-vector(b), do dotProduct(unit-vector(a), unit-vector(b))**

Comment: The answer by Nikolay Kuznetsov returns the angle formed by the line by the two points with respect to the absolute x-axis. As I have understood the question, we need the angle basepoint has to turn with respect to some initial direction it was pointing to.